# Arquillian don't clean deployment from JBoss when run from console

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I' am working on a JavaEE Project which we test with Arquillian.
All my Tests running well when I start them from Eclipse.
But when I start them from console Arquillian don't perfom an undeploy.
After the Tests are finished they leave a deployment entry in standalown.xml like these:

```html
<deployments>
  <deployment name="Absenz-ear.ear" runtime-name="Absenz-ear.ear">
    <content sha1="612823b52f0a4250c4fa889f885288c2d0ee24b6"/>
  </deployment>
</deployments>
```

And also the deployment won't clean from JBoss/standalone/data directory.

Did anyone have an idea how to solve the problem.

I'm Using WildFly 8.2 in managed mode (but in remote mode there is the same problem)

Comment: I'am using wildfly 8.2, arquillian 1.1.8, junit 4.12 and gradle 2.2.1