# Remove deployments from standalone.xml after arquillian test

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

After arquilliian test for our project, in wildfly standalone.xml the following entry is created.

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="cfgtest.ear" runtime-name="cfgtest.ear">
        <content sha1="b0f9e180aaa4e14ee9bab37b4368b6ce45b7b156"/>
    </deployment>
    <deployment name="pcuitest.ear" runtime-name="pcuitest.ear">
        <content sha1="884d1333731f6ed58eb47cee7d7a98a20829d373"/>
    </deployment>
</deployments>
```

Ideally the above should be removed once all  tests are completed and server is stopped, but thats not happening anyway. Now if I run the test for the second time -  at the time of server startup the above deployments gets started and it creates conflict with the new war files of the current test.

Is there any way I can remove the deployments entry from standalone.xml so that it wont get started when the server starts again. Any startup commands to server so it removes all the deployments or something like that would be helpful.

Note: I found that, If I run the test from eclipse, deployed ear's removed automatically while server stop. But if I run it from gradle, issue remains.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30752259/arquillian-dont-clean-deployment-from-jboss-when-run-from-console?rq=1
not answered.

Comment: Are you manually deploying applications or letting Arquillian manage the deployment lifecycle?

Comment: Arquillian is managing  the deployments.

Comment: That's weird then because they should be getting removed. What version of wildfly-arquillian are you using?

Comment: I'am using wildfly 8.2, arquillian 1.1.5, junit 4.12 and gradle 2.2

Comment: @James R. Perkins, any clue?

Comment: Sorry no I'm not sure. Arquillian should be removing the deployments after the tests are done. Maybe it's a Gradle issue, but that would seem a bit odd to me if it was.